Reusing Custom Node Groups in Different Materials
In my Blender file I created a node group called Metal Node. In this node group, I'm using a driver to control a factor position. In order for the driver to work properly, the driver references the specific material the node group is in. However, I would like to use Metal Node in multiple different materials, and I think it would defeat the purpose of having to change what should be a reusable node group's drivers every time I add the node group to a new material. Is there any way I can have the driver's value point to the node group itself rather than the material it's a part of?
For example, in Test Material A, the driver works as intended:
Here's the material output: 
The driver details: 
However, putting the same node in a different material (Test Material B), the node group no longer affects the driver's value as seen here:


But the mesh uses the driver value from Test Material A: 
Is there any way for the driver to either automatically reference the material it is in, or have the driver reference the node itself so it can be added to any material and automatically work as intended?
Edit: Sorry for any confusion, I meant a default value that can be changed by each node group instance. For example, the default factor value may be 0.5 for all node group instances, but in material A, the factor value could be 0.2 and in material B, the factor value could be 0.6.

Why don't you keep factor value inside the group, like this:

So that you don't need to drive the value, it will be the same for all materials that uses the node group.

Sorry for the confusion of my post, I meant a default value that can be changed by each node group instance. So the default value may be 0.5, but in material A, the value could be 0.2 and in material B, the value could be 0.6, for example
